# Espresso - click an image inside a gridview

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-espresso

I have a view hierarchy like below:

```
GridView{id=2131362110, res-name=item_list_grid, 
|
+----->RelativeLayout{id=2131362124, res-name=item_image_thumb_layout
|
+------------->ImageView{id=2131362125, res-name=item_image
|
+----->RelativeLayout{id=2131362124, res-name=item_image_thumb_layout
|
+------------->ImageView{id=2131362125, res-name=item_image
|
+------>RelativeLayout{id=2131362124, res-name=item_image_thumb_layout
|
+------------->ImageView{id=2131362125, res-name=item_image
|
GridView{id=2131362110, res-name=item_list_grid, ...etc
```

I want to perfom click on one of the ImageView with id=item_image.

I can not use something like atPosition(x) together with onView so instead I used onData. I tried all of these:

```
onData(allOf(anything(),withId(R.id.item_image))).atPosition(0).perform(click());

onData(anything()).atPosition(0).perform(click());

onData(allOf(atPosition(0),withId(R.id.item_image))).perform(click());
```

But all resulted in

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

Any suggestions for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your error message tell you have multiple views in your activity that extends form `AdapterView` so you have another `ListView` or `GridView` in your layout.

You can either select the `AdapterView` on the data layer. So select this `AdapterView` with items of type `ItemModel`

```
onData(is(instanceOf(ItemModel.class))).atPosition(0)
    .onChildView(withId(R.id.item_image)).perform(click());
```

or you can choose a specific `AdapterView` by id

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.my_grid_view)).atPosition(0).
            onChildView(withId(R.id.item_image)).perform(click());
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. I have 2 gridviews (I've edited my questions). The thing is both my gridviews have the same id. So I'm unable to use your second solution. My temporarily solution is: onData(instanceOf(Item.class)).atPosition(0).inAdapterView(allOf(withId(R.id.item_list_grid), isDisplayed())).perform(click()); I will test again your first solution to see if it works.

Comment: If your gridviews are having the same ids, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: this: 
 `onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.my_grid_view)).atPosition(0).perform(click());` was enough for me. tnx :)